# DropdownlistFor not binding with List of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have to bind a dropdownlistfor with a List like below

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model._list[0].cat_id, Model._ddlcategory, "Please Select Category", new { @class = "form-control", @tabindex = 4, @id = "ddlcategory" })
```

_list[0].cat_id has the value, but the dropdown list I am unable to bind. Can i know where I am going wrong?

Comment: What about the other values inside model._list[0]?

Comment: They are all getting binded with the textbox, only the dropdown binding is not working.

Comment: So you want to bind a list to a list? or is it a single value to a list?